# setwd not working when I run it within a .RMD file

Tags: r, r-markdown

I often set the working directory to the project directory at the start of each .rmd file I create. The default working directory is different.

Lately, I've noticed that it works when I first run it. But after saving the file and reopening it, it no longer resets the working directory. Here's what happens:

I run this code from the .rmd file

````
```{r}
setwd("/Users/ESElia/Documents/Data/R")
```
````

Then (because R can't find any files I try to load) I check the wd:

```
getwd()
```

and get this response:

> [1] "/Users/ESElia"

So then I re-set the wd in the console and check it:

```
setwd("/Users/ESElia/Documents/Data/R")
getwd()
```

and get the correct directory, finally!

> [1] "/Users/ESElia/Documents/Data/R"

Any idea why this is happening? is it a bug with a new version of something? I'm running RStudio Version 1.1.456, on a MacOS High Sierra 10.13.6. I know I can set the default directory to avoid this, but I'd prefer not to, since I have different .rmd files for different projects that operate out of different directories.

Comment: I'm not clear on the exact sequence of events here - setwd doesn't change the directory permanently

Comment: Please write down the _exact_ sequence of events, or provide a reproducible example. You do not mention how you run the .Rmd file. I would expect it to be run in a different environment, thus not touching your "current" path to working directory.

Comment: Consider avoiding use of `setwd()` and instead use relative paths in your projects (one approach is explained [here](https://github.com/jennybc/here_here)). To expand on @RomanLuštrik's comment, when you click the `knit` button to compile an `rmd` file, the document is compiled in a completely new and separate R session. Your interactive R commands don't affect this separate R session, nor does the separate R session affect your current interactive R session.

Comment: @eipi10 this may be unavoidable if you're linking to some common resource (e.g. big files or files that change and it would be a hassle to copy). Another option would be to use soft links, but then you have windows... Gah.

Comment: Thanks @RomanLuštrik and @eipi10. I have been running lines of the code from the R Markdown window in R Studio using the `command` + `return` keyboard shortcut. My guess is that you guys are right about the different environments. I'll look into the here package mentioned by @eipi10. But... what are soft links and is it something I code in R or something I have to do through terminal?

Comment: Not really sure if I used the term "soft link", but if you search for "symlink", any resource should get you started.

Comment: Thanks @RomanLuštrik !